# TypeError: Fire.default.shared.addPost is not a function' ,'Fire.default.shared.addPost' is undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native

hey guys i really need your help to get rid of this error.
here is the code

```
 handlePost = () => {
Fire.shared
  .addPost({
    text: this.state.text.trim(),
    localUri: this.state.image,
  })
  .then((ref) => {
    this.setState({ text: "", image: null });
    this.props.navigation.goBack();
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    alert(error.message);
  });
```

};

Comment: what is Fire? it seems like you're missing some context here

Comment: Fire is a file named Fire.js in my project